# How to get all images which uploaded manually in the Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm new in `Firebase` . I want to know if it is possible to download all images which uploaded manually ? I searched on this topic but I found that ,I need the image `URL` and save it in a `Firebase Realtime Database` , but in this case if I uploaded it programmatically . Is there another way ? because I want to upload it manually .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase client SDKs require you to know the name of a file in Cloud Storage in order to download it.  There are no bulk file download operations.

Comment: So in this way I have to get the  images' names and pass them in download function ?

Comment: Yes, you have to know the names of the files.